# Not able to test subscribe method in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

My ts file has a subscribe method in ngAfterViewInit() which is added below. So while writing test case and doing debugging its not coming inside subscribe method and setting that mock data. So for some testing purposes Ineed to set the same mock data inside subscribe method.

**ts file**

```
 import mockData from 'testing/mock-data.json';
 public assembly: Subject<AssemblyNotification[]>;
 private assemblyService: AssemblyService,
 this.assemblyService.assembly.subscribe() => {
     this.dataSource.data = mockData ;
});
```

**spec file**

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
 let component: MyComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

 const mockdata: any = require('testing/mock-data.json');
 const mockassemblyService = jasmine.createSpyObj(AssemblyService, [
  ]);
  mockassemblyService.assembly= new Subject<();
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
     HttpClientModule,
     RouterTestingModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: AssemblyService, useValue: assemblyService },
  ],
     schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
    assemblyService.assembly.next(mockdata);
   fixture.detectChanges();
  });

 it('should create', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });

it('should call subscribe method and set data', () => {
  expect(component.dataSource.data).toBe(mockdata);
});
});
```

Comment: Let me google it for you: https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async

Comment: An other link with angular code: https://baldur.gitbook.io/angular/angular-test/testing/using-fakeasync-to-test-async-observables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should most likely be `{}` instead of `[]` because `Jasmine` will complain that it is empty for methods to be mocked.

```
// Change [] to {} here
const mockassemblyService = jasmine.createSpyObj(AssemblyService, {});
mockassemblyService.assembly= new Subject<();
```

This should be `mockAssemblyService` here:

```
// !! Change assemblyService to mockAssemblyService here.
providers: [
    { provide: AssemblyService, useValue: mockAssemblyService},
  ]
```

You are facing an issue of early subscription or early emission.

Change the order of lines here (fixture.detectChanges() before next):

```
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // !! This fixture.detectChanges will call `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`
    // so the subscriptions are listening and then we next the data.
    fixture.detectChanges();
    assemblyService.assembly.next(mockdata);
  });
```

Before, the way you had it, we would next the data and then subscribe but it would never emit (late subscription).

Comment: Change the order of lines here (fixture.detectChanges() before next):...This worked...thanks